# Invalid response in Modbus_tk RTU master

Tags: python, modbus-tk

I am creating a GUI to read data from plc holding registors, I have tried `pymodbus` as well as `modbus_tk`. What I am suffering from is my code reads the values from desired address perfectly for up to 2 minutes and than I get an error.

In modbus_tk rtu I get error as bellow:

```py
modbus_tk.exceptions.ModbusInvalidResponseError: Response length is invalid 0
```

I have tried to add some delay between read commands but I am having the same results. Another thing is I need to do is log these values in an Excel file in future, so I cannot add a large delay as I need to record the response per second (or per some seconds).

Please help!